# I can't handle 'error message' on a POST method which comes from controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, xhtml, sails.js

I've been trying to handle a responded error message with jQuery on Sails.
I'm using a js file(login.js) to login website and using another js file named SessionController to hold my logic code.

Firstly, a jquery POST method in my login.js file is sending a request.
Secondly, deliberately, i'm trying to enter wrong username or password. But I can't handle error messages in the POST method.

The below codes return 'Forbidden' as error parameter and 'null' as xhr.getResponseHeader('error'). But I've expected "Username error" or "Password error".

What should I do? I'm open to advices...

### My login.js file

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#btn-login").click(function() {

        var username = $("#username").val();
        var password = $("#password").val();        
        if(!username) {

        } else if(!password) {

        } else {    
            // alert('It"s continuing to POST');
            $.post(
                '/login',
                { username: username, password: password },
                function() {
                    window.location = "/user/show/"
                }).fail(function(xhr, textStatus, error){

                    alert('xhr.statusText: ' + xhr.statusText);
                    alert('textStatus: ' + textStatus);
                    alert('error: ' + error);

                // $("#popupPaddedMessage").text("Error: " + xhr.getResponseHeader('error'));
                // $("#popupPadded").popup("open", { positionTo: "window" });

                });
        } 
    });

});
```

### My SessionController js file

```
module.exports = {

    create: function(req, res, next) {

        User.native(function(err, collectionUser) {

            if(err) { return err; };
            if(!collectionUser) { return err; };

            collectionUser
            .find({'username' : req.param('username')})
            .nextObject(function (err, user) {

                if(err) { 
                    res.send(500, { error: "Database error"});
                };

                if(!user) {
                    res.send(400, { error: "Username error"});
                };

                if(user) { 
                    if(user.password === req.param('password')) {
                        req.session.user = user;
                        res.send(user);
                        //res.redirect('/user/show/' + user[0]._id);
                    } else {                        
                        res.send(400, { error: "Password error"});
                    } 

                };                
            });
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: Are you sure your **SessionController** action is being run at all?  I don't see anything in there that would return a "forbidden" response.  I would 1) check if there are any policies being applied in **config/policies.js** that may be sending the "forbidden" response, and 2) put a `console.log` somewhere in the beginning of that controller action to check that it's being reached.

Comment: First of all thank you for your help, Scott. I've checked my **config/policies.js** . There has only "asteriks": true, . I've tried 'console.log()' in every conditional line, previously. It returned _Password error_ . I found Forbidden text in *views/403.ejs* '<html> <head> <title>Forbidden</title>...'

Comment: Try returning some error throught json.. Using `res.json({error: 'your error message'});` This would justify if the controller is being called and is returning some response..

Comment: What version of Sails are you using?

Comment: I'm using Sails v0.10.0-rc8